# How can i write sql function for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I pass this string as parameter into a SQL function 1,3,5,6

I need to generate the string like this in SQL functions

```
('1','3','5','6')
```

Using SQL Server I need to write the function.....

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: this is an implementation question. what are you REALLY trying to accomplish? put another way - why do you need that string. we might be able to help you skip a step

Comment: i have string like 1,3,5,6.... if i pass the string means using the sql function i need to return the o/p like this ....... '(''1'',''3'',''5'',''6'')' –

Comment: why? what is using this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select '('''''+REPLACE('1,3,5,6',',',''''',''''')+''''')' as Str
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27242)

Answer (score 1):

Declare @Ids varchar(50) Set @Ids = '1,2,3,5,4,6,7,98,234'

Select * from sometable
 where Charindex(','+cast(tableid as varchar(8000))+',', @Ids) > 0